# Asp.net 4.0 URL rewrite assistance

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble trying to rewrite a url using asp.net 4.0; I keep getting a server error when doing so.

Current url: http://www.somesite.com/contact.aspx

Desired url: http://www.somesite.com/contact-us

Thanks in advance for looking.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs